# Why do non-informative a priori distributions be chosen to compare the Bayesian and frequentist estimation method?

Tags: bayesian, prior, garch, frequentist, volatility-forecasting

For example for GARCH models 
$$\sigma_t^2=\alpha_0 +\alpha_1 y_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1  \sigma^2_{t-1}$$

it is usual to use as distributions for the parameters of truncated normal distributions with very high variance so as not to give any a priori information and then compare the estimate with the frequentistist approach through The Maximum Likelihood estimation.

In this case the two estimation approaches should not give the same result? We find that the distribution of the parameters of the GARCH is asymmetric as in the work of David Ardia **"Financial Risk Management with Bayesian Estimation
of GARCH Models"** where we can find that:

> ..we note that even though the number of observations is large, the ML
>   results and the Bayesian posterior means are different; the ML point
>   estimate is lower for $\alpha$ components of vector and higher for $\beta$ parameter